# Why anonymous methods inside structs can not access instance members of 'this'

Tags: c#

I have a code like the following:

```
struct A
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(i => i == _field);
    }

    int _field;
}
```

... and then i get the following compiler error:

> Anonymous methods inside structs can not access instance members of  'this'.

Can anybody explains what's going on here.

Comment: See the following article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/grantri/archive/2004/02/05/68526.aspx

Comment: As a quick fix, you can store the struct in a local variable: `A thisA = this; var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(i => i == thisA._field);`

Comment: That will not do what most people expect, though, see my answer (updated)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Variables are captured by reference (even if they *were* actually value-types; boxing is done then).

However, `this` in a ValueType (struct) cannot be boxed, and hence you cannot capture it.

Eric Lippert has a nice article on the surprises of capturing ValueTypes. Let me find the link

- [The Truth About Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-truth-about-value-types)

---

Note in response to the comment by Chris Sinclair:

> As a quick fix, you can store the struct in a local variable: `A thisA = this; var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(i => i == thisA._field);` – [Chris Sinclair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269654/chris-sinclair) [4 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801462/why-anonymous-methods-inside-structs-can-not-access-instance-members-of-this/12801567#comment17310741_12801462)

Beware of the fact that this creates surprising situations: the *identity* of `thisA` is **not** the same as `this`. More explicitly, if you choose to keep the *lambda* around longer, it will have the boxed **copy** `thisA` captured by reference, and **not** the actual instance that `SomeMethod` was called on.

Comment: updated link: [The Truth About Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-truth-about-value-types) (can't seem to edit or see if anyone's already made this edit)

Answer (score 3):

When you have an anonymous method it will be compiled into a new class, that class will have one method (the one you define).  It will also have a reference to each variable that you used that was outside of the scope of the anonymous method.  It's important to emphasize that it is a reference, not a copy, of that variable.  "lambdas close over variables, not values" as the saying goes.  This means that if you close over a variable outside of the scope of a lambda, and then change that variable after defining the anonymous method (but before invoking it) then you will see the changed value when you do invoke it).

So, what's the point of all of that.  Well, if you were to close over `this` for a struct, which is a value type, it's possible for the lambda to outlive the struct.  The anonymous method will be in a *class*, not a struct, so it will go on the heap, live as long as it needs to, and you are free to pass a reference to that class (directly or indirectly) wherever you want.

Now imagine that we have a local variable, with a struct of the type you've defined here.  We use this named method to generate a lambda, and let's assume for a moment that the query `items` is returned (instead of the method being `void`).  Would could then store that query in another instance (instead of local) variable, and iterate over that query some time later on another method.  What would happen here?  In essence, we would have held onto a reference to a value type that was on the stack once it is no longer in scope.

What does that mean?  The answer is, [we have no idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794).  (Please look over the link; it's kinda the crux of my argument.)  The data could just happen to be the same, it could have been zeroed out, it could have been filled by entirely different objects, there is no way of knowing.  C# goes to great lengths, as a language, to prevent you from doing things like this.  Languages such as C or C++ don't try so hard to stop you from shooting your own foot.

Now, in this particular case, it's possible that you aren't going to use the lambda outside of the scope of what `this` refers to, but the compiler doesn't know that, and if it lets you create the lambda it has no way of determining whether or not you expose it in a way that could result in it outliving `this`, so the only way to prevent this problem is to disallow some cases that aren't actually problematic.